# Unable to run PowerShell Script in GitHub Actions due to ParentContainsErrorRecordException: error

Tags: powershell, github, continuous-integration, workflow, github-actions

I have a simple work flow file

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-2019

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Get Repos
  run: ./Snippet/getrepo2.ps1
  env: 
    PAT: ${{ secrets.My_PAT }} #I have the secret on Github
    OrgName: MyOrg
  shell: pwsh
```

However I keep getting the error below when I run the workflow:

```
ParentContainsErrorRecordException: 
Line |
  3 |  $RawUI.CursorPosition = @{X=0;Y=0}
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception setting "CursorPosition": "The handle is invalid."
```

The PowerShell file looks like:

```
$PAT = $env:PAT, # This token MUST have admin rights
$OrgName = $env:OrgName
[string]$userName = 'NotNeeded'
[string]$userPassword = $PAT
# Convert to SecureString
[securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force
#Create the credential
[pscredential]$credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName,$secStringPassword)
Set-GitHubAuthentication -Credential $credObject -SessionOnly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# Access the Organizational Repo
$OrganizationalRepos = Get-GitHubRepository -OrganizationName $OrgName
Write-Host $OrganizationalRepos.name
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The Gitlab Actions runner is likely running headless, meaning there is no `$RawUI` you can modify. `New-Object` and `ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force` won't attempt to modify the UI, so my best bet is that `Get-GitHubRepository` or `Set-GitHubAuthentication` is responsible. Where did you obtain those functions?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen those are PowershellforGithub module commands to get the list of all repos in a github organization.